# How do I add Auto-Increment ID Column to a table generated from SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table generated from SQL Query itself. Now I need to add an auto incremental id column into this table.
Usual syntax to add auto incremental id column is-

```
ALTER TABLE *Table_Name* ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

But I don't have a specific table name, the table is generated from a query.

Comment: Hi @Sayyam, as i can predict,  you need to create dynamic query (Alter command). If not, Please more clarify your problem with example.

Comment: you have to alter the table , or its ok to create the rownumber dynamically too ? please let me know so i delete my answer or keep it

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
## Your Query to generate the Tablename
SELECT "myTable" INTO @mytab;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",@mytab," ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST");
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> desc myTable;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| insertat | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| myval    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from myTable;
+------------+-------+
| insertat   | myval |
+------------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 |    44 |
| 2021-01-02 |    99 |
| 2021-01-02 |   134 |
| 2021-01-03 |    45 |
| 2021-01-04 |     2 |
| 2021-01-04 |    17 |
+------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> ## Your Query to generate the Tablename
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT "myTable" INTO @mytab;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> 
MariaDB [bernd]> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",@mytab," ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [bernd]> desc myTable;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| insertat | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| myval    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> select * from myTable;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | insertat   | myval |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2021-01-01 |    44 |
|  2 | 2021-01-02 |    99 |
|  3 | 2021-01-02 |   134 |
|  4 | 2021-01-03 |    45 |
|  5 | 2021-01-04 |     2 |
|  6 | 2021-01-04 |    17 |
+----+------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: see manual :-) : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dual/

Comment: also in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Wow, dang - egg-on-face moment there! Weird that I didn't spot that from the search results. I've deleted my incorrect comments.

Comment: but i normally never use it - i have removed it from my answer

Comment: Mysql does not support execute immediate, only mariadb does. The question is tagged as mysql.